# Is there a way to get multiple ngram orders using NTLK instead of obtaining a iterating over a generator?

Tags: python, nlp, generator, nltk, n-gram

I need ngrams. I know `nltk.utils.ngrams` can be used to obtain ngrams, but in practice, the ngrams function returns a generator object. I can always iterate over it and store the ngrams in a list. But is there another, more direct way to obtaining these ngrams in a list without having to iterate over them?

Comment: `someList = list(someGenerator)` - would that work?

Comment: nope. returns an empty list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@georg's comment pretty much nails it.

```
In [12]: from nltk.util import ngrams

In [13]: g = ngrams([1,2,3,4,5], 3)

In [14]: list(g)
Out[14]: [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]

In [15]: g = ngrams([1,2,3,4,5], 3)

In [16]: map(lambda x: x, g)
Out[16]: [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

Comment: Indeed! something's up with my python interpreter... it refused to work the first time i tried. works now. Thanks!

Comment: Short question, why are you using `map` when you can instantiate/materialize a generator with `list`? Is there a difference in efficiency?

Comment: @alvas Not that I know of.  I was just trying to show different ways.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a built-in function to get multiple orders of ngrams call `everygrams` ,see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/util.py#L504

```
>>> from nltk import everygrams
>>> sent = 'a b c'.split()
# By default, it will extract every possible order of ngrams.
>>> list(everygrams(sent))
[('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
# You can set a max order or ngrams.
>>> list(everygrams(sent, max_len=2))
[('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')]
# Or specify a range.
>>> list(everygrams(sent, min_len=2, max_len=3))
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

or alternatively without `nltk`:

```
from itertools import chain

def ngrams(L, n = 2):
    orders = [n] if type(n) is int else sorted(list(n))
    return list(chain(*[zip(*[L[i:] for i in range(n)]) for n in orders]))

>>> ngrams([1,2,3,4,5], n = 3)
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
>>> ngrams([1,2,3,4,5], n = [2,3])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```